# java code to create json array

Tags: java, json

```
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>

<%@page import="java.lang.Thread.State"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONArray"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.io.*,java.sql.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"


 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

try{


Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String mySqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/permit"; 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(mySqlUrl ,"root","moodle123");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from enterprisemaster where `enterpriseId=1001");`
JSONArray respJson = new JSONArray(); 
java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();


 while (rs.next()) { 

    JSONObject obj  = new JSONObject();
    for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {

        String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        obj.put(columnName, rs.getString(columnName));

    }
    respJson.put(obj);


  }
    respJson.toString();
    System.out.println(respJson);
}
catch(Exception e)
{ 
System.out.println(e);  
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

type Exception report

```
    message An exception occurred processing JSP page /JsonCreation.jsp at line 36

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling 

    this request.

        exception 

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page 

    /JsonCreation.jsp at line 36

    33:             obj.put(columnName, rs.getString(columnName));

    34:         
    35:         }
    36:         respJson.put(obj);
    37:     }
    38:     respJson.toString();
    39:     System.out.println(respJson);

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ezmorph/Morpher
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.JsonCreation_jsp._jspService(JsonCreation_jsp.java:119)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ezmorph/Morpher
    net.sf.json.JSONArray.put(JSONArray.java:1296)
    org.apache.jsp.JsonCreation_jsp._jspService(JsonCreation_jsp.java:101)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ezmorph.Morpher
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    net.sf.json.JSONArray.put(JSONArray.java:1296)
    org.apache.jsp.JsonCreation_jsp._jspService(JsonCreation_jsp.java:101)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47                        logs.
```

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ezmorph/Morpher 
What is this class? Is it a dependency? Looks like Java can't find it.

Comment: actually the error is shown in line 36 jasonarrayobject.put's definition is not being detected

Comment: Nah, I'm pretty sure you're problem is that it can't find the class net/sf/ezmorph/Morpher...

Comment: ezmorph.jar is already there in the lib

Comment: Is it on the classpath?

Comment: its in lib folder as well the buildpath

Comment: How are you running/deploying the application?

Comment: <%@page import="org.json.JSONArray "%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject" %> i changed the jar file it is working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@page import="org.json.JSONArray "%> <%@page import="org.json.JSONObject" %>
```

i changed the jar file it is working fine now

```
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONArray"%>
```

was conflicting with above jars and net.*....
jar was corrupt

Answer (score 0):

As per the stacktrace, the `net/sf/ezmorph/Morpher` class is not found.

Please make sure you add [`ezmorph.jar`](http://www.findjar.com/class/net/sf/ezmorph/Morpher.html;jsessionid=7B74114C89BB3E72E45ED2E07766C92C) to your class path i.e the `WEB-INF/lib` folder

Comment: I copied the same code and runned inside a main method as java class then the  it worked and output was recieved

Comment: It works because the jar is available in your build path(hope you are using eclipse)-It has to work if you add that to lib . No other solutions I have....

Comment: yeah i am using eclipse previously i had added the jar files before posting the question here but that dint help <%@page import="org.json.JSONArray "%> <%@page import="org.json.JSONObject" %> i changed the jar file it is working fine now